systemd CPU usage meaning
Question 1:
With systemctl status name.service, one of the lines I get is:
CPU: 3.555s

But I could not find any info on what does it mean.
Since it is in seconds, I guess this is the total CPU time consumed by the cgroup, but I would like to have a confirmation, or a manpage where this is explained.
Question 2:
If my assumption is true, combining this with the uptime of the cgroup from the line
Active: active (running) since Sun 2024-06-23 13:54:29 CEST; 12min ago

will give me the average percentage of CPU time this process is consuming, is that right?

Question 1
It's almost certainly going to be the value of the kernel's runtime counter, which gets updated every context switch. So, yes, that's pretty much what you describe. However, we can be sure. This answer strives to explain how one can figure such things out oneself. I'm not a kernel hacker or systemd developer. But using sensible tools (rg and git grep for searching from the command line, your favourite text editor with "search for word under cursor" functionality, in my case neovim with telescope):
clone systemd. One rg CPU: later:
systemd/src/systemctl/systemctl-show.c

printf("        CPU: %s\n", FORMAT_TIMESPAN(i->cpu_usage_nsec / NSEC_PER_USEC, USEC_PER_MSEC));


i here is a UnitStatusInfo, getting populated via dbus in bus_map_all_properties(…, "org.freedesktop.systemd1", …);. The bus_properties_map property_map contains the key with which the datum is requested:

{ "CPUUsageNSec",                   "t",               NULL,           offsetof(UnitStatusInfo, cpu_usage_nsec)                    },


so, looking for "CPUUsageNSec" leads us to systemd/src/core/dbus-unit.c's property_get_cpu_usage function; which calls unit_get_cpu_usage; which is defined in cgroup.c, where it calls unit_get_cpu_usage_raw.
First case: the unit runs in the root cgroup; then it just reads /proc/{pid}/stat:
        /* The root cgroup doesn't expose this information, let's get it from /proc instead */
        if (unit_has_host_root_cgroup(u))
                return procfs_cpu_get_usage(ret);

Otherwise, it gets the data driectly from the cgroup's cpu.stat (so, cgroupv2's cpu controller). As man cgroups tells us, these are documented in the kernel's Documentation/admin-guide/cgroup-v2.rst.
So, that's always the same statistic as you're used to: from entering your task to exiting it, how much time was spent on it?
You can read the authorative information on how that is accounted in the kernel's sched/rstat.c  and most importantly cputime.c. You'll find that I have addressed exactly that in Is the information read in /proc/*pid*/stat updated by a timer interrupt? already :)
Question 2

If my assumption is true, combining this with the uptime of the cgroup
from the line
Active: active (running) since Sun 2024-06-23 13:54:29 CEST; 12min ago
will give me the average percentage of CPU time this process is
consuming, is that right?

No, because CPUs these days are put to sleep, reduced in clock frequency and spun up again at micro- to millisecond scale. So, the "comparable" CPU·1s unit really hasn't existed for years, and from the pure CPU time accounting, it's impossible to know whether a task just spent doing little on a CPU core clocked down to 800 MHz, or whether what it did kept a complete CPU double-core (hyperthreading) active at 3.8 GHz. A multi-core CPU where all 16 cores are running at 3.8 GHz continuously has a lot more CPU cycles to spend than a multi-core CPU where 1 core is running at 800 MHz to deal with some service waking up on a counter every 10 ms, and the other 15 are off. However, it will still look as if the one service used 1/16 of all CPU time. That's just not what happened – if there was more things to be done, the scheduler would wake up more cores, and increase the clock rates.
Accounting for share of CPU time on frequency-scalable multiprocessor systems is hard, and it leads to things like people optimizing their server workloads for the thing that gives them the most performance per CPU minute paid to AWS, Azure, GCloud, Alibaba Cloud, Oracle…, even if that is by no means the most energy-efficient or fastest possible. It's an interesting field!

Very well written! Looking at procfs_cpu_get_usage() at https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/main/src/basic/procfs-util.c#L130 , the time is calculated with ticks/(tick/sec). Obviously, tick/sec is queried after the code has run, and the proc freq may have been adjusted in the meantime. But in the past, I had good results reducing the measured runtime variance by querying the CPU freq after the code has run, and adjusting with that. The number of CPU threads actually involved is still an issue though, if wall clock and CPU time is to be compared.
